# 'module' object has no attribute 'SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY'

Tags: python, django

excuese me everyone:
I am trying to practice Django by a book "light weight Django",however I got the error 'module' object has no attribute 'SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY' .

error:

[image]
the working tree:
[image]

prototypes.py:

```
import os
import sys
from django.conf import settings

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_URL='/static/',
SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pages'),

settings.configure(
    DEBUG = True,
    SECRET_KEY= 'qfzf!b1z^5dyk%syiokeg4*2xf%kj68g=o&e8qvd@@(1lj5z8)',
    ROOT_URLCONF='sitebuilder.urls',
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(),
    INSTALLED_APPS=(
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'sitebuilder',
    ),
    TEMPLATES=(
        {
            'BACKEND':'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS':[],
            'APP_DIRS':True,
        },
    ),
    STATIC_URL='/static/',
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

views.py:

```
import os

from django.conf import settings
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import Template
from django.utils._os import safe_join


def get_page_or_404(name):
    try:
        file_path = safe_join(settings.SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY, name)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404('Page Not Found')
    else:
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            raise Http404('Page Not Found')

    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        page = Template(f.read())
    return page


def page(request, slug='index'):
    file_name = '{}.html'.format(slug)
    page = get_page_or_404(file_name)
    context = {
        'slug':slug,
        'page':page,
    }
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import page

urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w./-]+)/$', page, name='page'),
    url(r'^$', page, name='homepage'),
)
```

can anyone tell me why it has error please,very thanks!!

Comment: Well, you've asked for something called `settings.SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY` in your `get_page_or_404` function, but you never defined any setting called that.

Comment: I think  I have  defined  the "settings.SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY" in prototypes.py right?

Comment: But you haven't passed it into settings.configure().

Comment: thank you ,,I got it,,then I moved the SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pages') to within the settings.configure(), it works!!

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pages')
```

should be inside

```
settings.configure()
```

not outside, i.e.

```
settings.configure(
    DEBUG = True,
    SECRET_KEY= 'qfzf!b1z^5dyk%syiokeg4*2xf%kj68g=o&e8qvd@@(1lj5z8)',
    ROOT_URLCONF='sitebuilder.urls',
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(),
    INSTALLED_APPS=(
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'sitebuilder',
    ),
    TEMPLATES=(
        {
            'BACKEND':'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS':[],
            'APP_DIRS':True,
        },
    ),
    STATIC_URL='/static/',
    SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pages'), #RIGHT HERE
)
```